# Failing to open advanced-cache.php which is breaking Media Library

Tags: media-library, cache, debug, settings-api

On my WordPress install, which is 3.8 and has all plugins updated, it is using Magic Fields 2 and Hypercache amongst other plugins. I can't insert images into posts because when I upload, it gives me an error:

> An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.

The Media Library window from a post's "Insert Media" appears blank although I know there are images there and can view them by going there in the sidebar. When I try to insert images with a Magic Field, when I click "insert into post", the window is blank and it doesn't insert the image.

In wp-config.php, I've set debugging to true:

> define('WP_DEBUG', true);

And I'm getting these errors with ALL plugins disabled and the problem not resolved:

> Warning: include(/myPath/wordpress/wp-content/advanced-cache.php)
>   [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>   in /myPath/wordpress/wp-settings.php on line 65
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   '/myPath/wordpress/wp-content/advanced-cache.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php') in
>   /myPath/wordpress/wp-settings.php on line 65

I've checked the wp-content folder and am not seeing an advanced-cache.php - is the issue here that it SHOULD exist? Any suggestions?

---

UPDATE 4/27/2014

So as per Milo's suggestion, I went and set wp_cache to false:

define('WP_CACHE', false);

And I can insert images into regular posts again. I can't, however, insert images with the media type magic field still - same issue. When I click "set image" and choose an image to "insert into post", the window turns blank and the image never goes into the field if I refresh the page.

[image: Magic Field where "Set Image" is]
[image: The window appears to choose an image for the Magic Field]
[image: I choose an image and tried several sizes, and click "insert into post"]
[image: And this is the blank window once I've clicked "insert into post"]

The only errors I'm seeing with wp_debug still true is:

> Notice: get_plugin_data was called with an argument that is deprecated
>   since version 3.0! The Site Wide Only: true plugin header is
>   deprecated. Use Network: true instead. in
>   /myPath/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3006

I only see this errors on the Plugins page. And then I'm also getting a console error on the page where I'm trying to change those Magic Fields:

> TypeError: a.ref is undefined

Pointing to wp-includes/js/tinymce/tiny_mce.js

So, suspecting maybe I had a script error in my theme files, I commented out all my js. Console error is now gone.

But I still can't insert an image with Magic Fields - this has happened to me before when upgrading to 3.8 - and I just can't remember what the cause of it was after going through deprecated code. Open to more suggestions.

Comment: `advanced-cache.php` is written by the cache plugin. WordPress is trying to load it because you have the `WP_CACHE` constant set in your `wp-config.php` file.

Comment: Hi Milo, so if I remove that constant in wp-config or add in that file where the errors points in the paths - it should work? I'll give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: I've changed define('WP_CACHE', true); to false in my config file and that made those cache errors stop. I can insert an image into a post again but I'm still having issues inserting images with magic fields, will updated my question with details.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like whatever the issue is has something to do with upgrading to 3.8 and Magic Fields V2 being up to date. I changed define('WP_CACHE', true); to false, made sure WordPress was up to date, made sure Magic Fields V2 is up to date, no other plugins were active and there were no other PHP errors in my log or with WP_DEBUG. And suddenly it was fine. I re-activated everything and it's been fine since.